# How make form visible after clicking search button in adf Query?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hello I am developing a web applicaiton using Oracle ADF and jdeveloper11.1.2.4. Actually I have a page with the fllowing query and a form. Searching and everything is fine but when the page is loaded for the first time from is empty. It is not looking good. So my Idea is this form should be initially invisible  and it should be visible only after user hits search button in Search from(af:query).

[image]

Please help me. How I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

The following is my .jsf code

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <af:document title="Search/Modfiy KPI" id="d1">
        <af:messages id="m1"/>
        <af:form id="f1">
            <af:pageTemplate viewId="/adminPageTemplate.jsf" id="pt1">
                <f:facet name="Center">
                    <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1">
                        <f:facet name="bottom"/>
                        <f:facet name="center">
                            <af:panelSplitter id="ps1" orientation="vertical" dimensionsFrom="children"
                                              splitterPosition="191">
                                <f:facet name="first">
                                    <af:panelGroupLayout layout="vertical" id="pgl1">

                                            <af:query id="qryId1" headerText="Search KPI" disclosed="true"
                                                      value="#{bindings.KpiSearchCriteriaQuery.queryDescriptor}"
                                                      model="#{bindings.KpiSearchCriteriaQuery.queryModel}"
                                                      queryOperationListener="#{bindings.KpiSearchCriteriaQuery.processQueryOperation}"
                                                      fieldWidth="110"
                                                      queryListener="#{pageFlowScope.updateORDeleteBean.customSearch}"
                                                      partialTriggers="::pfl1"/>

                                    </af:panelGroupLayout>
                                </f:facet>
                                <f:facet name="second">
                                    <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl5" layout="vertical" halign="center">
                                        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl3" layout="horizontal" halign="center">
                                            <af:panelGroupLayout layout="horizontal" id="pgl2">
                                                <f:facet name="separator">
                                                    <af:spacer width="10" height="1" id="s1"/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.First.execute}"
                                                                  text="First" disabled="#{!bindings.First.enabled}"
                                                                  partialSubmit="true" id="cb1"/>
                                                <af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.Previous.execute}"
                                                                  text="Previous"
                                                                  disabled="#{!bindings.Previous.enabled}"
                                                                  partialSubmit="true" id="cb2"/>
                                                <af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.Next.execute}" text="Next"
                                                                  disabled="#{!bindings.Next.enabled}"
                                                                  partialSubmit="true" id="cb3"/>
                                                <af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.Last.execute}" text="Last"
                                                                  disabled="#{!bindings.Last.enabled}"
                                                                  partialSubmit="true" id="cb4"/>
                                            </af:panelGroupLayout>
                                            <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s3"/>
                                            <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl4" layout="horizontal">
                                                <af:commandButton text="Delete" id="cb5"
                                                                  actionListener="#{updateORDeleteBean.delete}"/>
                                                <af:spacer width="10" height="10" id="s2"/>
                                                <af:commandButton text="Update" id="cb6"
                                                                  actionListener="#{updateORDeleteBean.update}"/>
                                            </af:panelGroupLayout>
                                        </af:panelGroupLayout>
                                        <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1" visible="#{pageFlowScope.showForm}">
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.Id.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.Id.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.Id.hints.mandatory}"
                                                          columns="#{bindings.Id.hints.displayWidth}"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.Id.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.Id.hints.tooltip}" id="it1"
                                                          readOnly="true">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Id.validator}"/>
                                                <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.Id.format}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.KpiName.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.KpiName.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.KpiName.hints.mandatory}" columns="110"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.KpiName.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.KpiName.hints.tooltip}" id="it2">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.KpiName.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.KpiSql.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.KpiSql.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.KpiSql.hints.mandatory}" columns="110"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.KpiSql.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.KpiSql.hints.tooltip}" id="it3"
                                                          rows="3">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.KpiSql.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.Category.inputValue}"
                                                                label="#{bindings.Category.label}"
                                                                required="#{bindings.Category.hints.mandatory}"
                                                                shortDesc="#{bindings.Category.hints.tooltip}"
                                                                id="soc1">
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.Category.items}" id="si1"/>
                                            </af:selectOneChoice>
                                            <af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.Module.inputValue}"
                                                                label="#{bindings.Module.label}"
                                                                required="#{bindings.Module.hints.mandatory}"
                                                                shortDesc="#{bindings.Module.hints.tooltip}" id="soc2">
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.Module.items}" id="si2"/>
                                            </af:selectOneChoice>
                                            <af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.Submodule.inputValue}"
                                                                label="#{bindings.Submodule.label}"
                                                                required="#{bindings.Submodule.hints.mandatory}"
                                                                shortDesc="#{bindings.Submodule.hints.tooltip}"
                                                                id="soc3">
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.Submodule.items}" id="si3"/>
                                            </af:selectOneChoice>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.Threshold.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.Threshold.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.Threshold.hints.mandatory}" columns="15"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.Threshold.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.Threshold.hints.tooltip}" id="it4">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Threshold.validator}"/>
                                                <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false"
                                                                  pattern="#{bindings.Threshold.format}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.Operator1.inputValue}"
                                                                label="#{bindings.Operator1.label}"
                                                                required="#{bindings.Operator1.hints.mandatory}"
                                                                shortDesc="#{bindings.Operator1.hints.tooltip}"
                                                                id="soc4">
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.Operator1.items}" id="si4"/>
                                            </af:selectOneChoice>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.Helptext.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.Helptext.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.Helptext.hints.mandatory}" columns="110"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.Helptext.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.Helptext.hints.tooltip}" id="it5">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Helptext.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.PerfReason.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.PerfReason.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.PerfReason.hints.mandatory}"
                                                          columns="110"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.PerfReason.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.PerfReason.hints.tooltip}" id="it6">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.PerfReason.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.XaxisDescription.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.XaxisDescription.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.XaxisDescription.hints.mandatory}"
                                                          columns="110"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.XaxisDescription.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.XaxisDescription.hints.tooltip}"
                                                          id="it7">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.XaxisDescription.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.YaxisDesciption.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.YaxisDesciption.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.YaxisDesciption.hints.mandatory}"
                                                          columns="110"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.YaxisDesciption.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.YaxisDesciption.hints.tooltip}"
                                                          id="it8">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.YaxisDesciption.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.Dschemaname.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.Dschemaname.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.Dschemaname.hints.mandatory}"
                                                          columns="50"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.Dschemaname.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.Dschemaname.hints.tooltip}" id="it9">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Dschemaname.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.Dtablename.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.Dtablename.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.Dtablename.hints.mandatory}"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.Dtablename.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.Dtablename.hints.tooltip}" id="it10"
                                                          columns="50">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Dtablename.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.Dfieldname.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.Dfieldname.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.Dfieldname.hints.mandatory}" columns="50"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.Dfieldname.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.Dfieldname.hints.tooltip}" id="it11">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Dfieldname.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.Toemail.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.Toemail.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.Toemail.hints.mandatory}" columns="50"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.Toemail.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.Toemail.hints.tooltip}" id="it12">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Toemail.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.CcEmail.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.CcEmail.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.CcEmail.hints.mandatory}" columns="50"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.CcEmail.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.CcEmail.hints.tooltip}" id="it13">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.CcEmail.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <af:selectOneChoice value="#{bindings.AutomoniterEnabled.inputValue}"
                                                                label="#{bindings.AutomoniterEnabled.label}"
                                                                required="#{bindings.AutomoniterEnabled.hints.mandatory}"
                                                                shortDesc="#{bindings.AutomoniterEnabled.hints.tooltip}"
                                                                id="soc5">
                                                <f:selectItems value="#{bindings.AutomoniterEnabled.items}" id="si5"/>
                                            </af:selectOneChoice>
                                            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.AuditInfo.inputValue}"
                                                          label="#{bindings.AuditInfo.hints.label}"
                                                          required="#{bindings.AuditInfo.hints.mandatory}"
                                                          columns="#{bindings.AuditInfo.hints.displayWidth}"
                                                          maximumLength="#{bindings.AuditInfo.hints.precision}"
                                                          shortDesc="#{bindings.AuditInfo.hints.tooltip}" id="it14"
                                                          readOnly="true">
                                                <f:validator binding="#{bindings.AuditInfo.validator}"/>
                                            </af:inputText>
                                            <f:facet name="footer"/>
                                        </af:panelFormLayout>
                                    </af:panelGroupLayout>
                                </f:facet>
                            </af:panelSplitter>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="start"/>
                        <f:facet name="end"/>
                        <f:facet name="top"/>
                    </af:panelStretchLayout>
                </f:facet>
            </af:pageTemplate>
        </af:form>
    </af:document>
</f:view>
```

The follwoing si my Java class code

```
public void customSearch(QueryEvent queryEvent) {
    // Add event code here...
    System.out.println("in custom srch");
    AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope().put("showForm", true);

    invokeEL("#{bindings.KpiSearchCriteriaQuery.processQuery}", new Class[] { QueryEvent.class },
             new Object[] { queryEvent });
    System.out.println("end custom srch");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flap "visible" property to true on your panelFormLayout only when user presses "Search" button:

```
 <af:panelFormLayout visible="#{pageFlowScope.showForm}">
```

For this you need to override "queryListener" method of your af:query:

```
<af:query queryListener="#{yourBean.customSearch}"/>
```

In your YourBean.java, you will have:

```
    public void customSearch(QueryEvent queryEvent) {

        AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPageFlowScope().put("showForm", true);

        //call your original queryListener- the one you changed in page: 
        invokeEL("#{bindings.DepartmentsViewCriteriaQuery.processQuery}", new Class[] { QueryEvent.class },
                     new Object[] { queryEvent });

    }
```

More details, here:
http://www.awasthiashish.com/2013/12/overriding-default-query-listener-field.html

Comment: Thanks for you time Marcus. I tried with your answer. I followe every step. customSearch(QueryEvent queryEvent) method is working properly. Means SerchCriteria is working. But this visiblity solution is notworking.

Comment: I have set form visible = #{pageFlowScope.updateORDeleteBean.showForm}. And I have copy pasted the above code. But visibility is not turning on or off.

Comment: you need to set a partial trigger on panelFormLayout, pointing to af:query

Comment: Tried marcus. No luck.

Comment: Two problems with the code:
1. You are setting the partial trigger the wrong way. It should be on panelFormLayout component.
2. Visible property should be: visible="#{pageFlowScope.showForm}"

Comment: Thank you . I have changed my code and posted in question. Still the problem is same. Can you check once agian. Thank you.

Comment: You didn't follow instruction no 1: panelFormLayout doesn't have 'partialTriggers' attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and time. It is working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Marcus it is working if I set partialTriggers for panelFormLayout. But it is not working if I set partialTriggers for panelGroupLayout(Means I need to manage panelGroupLayout visibility). Why like this?? Could you please tell me.

Comment: That's strange. The way I see it - it should work from panelGroupLayout as well.